# Debugging with exceptions: How to work around 'Break when thrown'

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, exception

I'm getting tired of clearing the Debugging->Exceptions option `Break when thrown` to get past an exception I handle properly, then setting the `Break when thrown` option to find the source of a subsequent exception not handled properly.

I would like a way to exclude certain try blocks from `Break when thrown`, with something like preprocessor directives or something.  I tried recording a macro, but all it does is opens the Debugging->Exceptions dialogue.

It would be nice to specify, even at a coarser grain, which methods are exempt from `Break when thrown` debugging.

Is this a pipe dream?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958011/toggle-break-when-an-exception-is-thrown-using-macro-or-keyboard-shortcut

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Push Alt-Ctrl-e to bring up the exceptions window.

Specify which exceptions you wish to ignore.

Comment: Nice advice, but I'm an idealist and would like to only ignore, e.g. SqlException, in certain code.

Comment: So you want to ignore it in Code X, but pay attention to it in Code Y?

Comment: Yep - I'm thinking of finding a way of communicating with the debugger dynamically.