# Is it possible to communicate with the Visual Studio debugger programmatically while debugging?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I would like to control options on the debugger without using the debugging GUI's, preferably from inside the code being debugged.  I would think that would be quite difficult, but maybe my debugged code can request a service from independent code that will communicate with the debugger.

This relates to [another question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201182/debugging-with-exceptions-how-to-work-around-break-when-thrown#201197) on controlling when to break on exceptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write Visual Studio macros that can do anything the GUI can, but they can get rather involved. See the MSDN documentation on [Automation and Extensibility for Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc52cke4(VS.80).aspx)

Doing this from the code being debugged would be tricky, you would definitely need some new form of communication with VS, maybe a custom add-in.  I don't think an independent service would fundamentally help here.  The biggest problem is that your code will stop running when the debugger breaks.

Comment: That's cool, as long as it's done what it has to when the debugger breaks.

Answer (score 0):

I know that you can do it with WinDBG and OutputDebugString, but for Visual Studio, I think you have to spool off another process, pipe commands to that, and have that manipulate the Debugger API.