# How can you debug across projects in VB.Net if one launches the other?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, projects-and-solutions, command-line-arguments

I have a VS 2008 Solution in VB.Net that has 2 projects - a Launcher and the App.  The Launcher is what runs first, checks to make sure the App has all the latest files from the network, etc. and then launches the App.  The Launcher allows the user to select their environment (Test, Production) then passes those values into the App.exe as command line arguments.

This works fine when running normally, but when trying to debug this, I'm trying to figure out how to start Debugging from the Launcher, then pass the selected Environment into the other project so it can read them as command line arguments. Thanks.

Comment: A little background info on why VS might not support automatically attaching to child processes: http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2009/07/20/can-the-vs-debugger-automatically-attach-to-any-child-spawned-by-a-process-being-debugged.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to launch your executable without debugging and then attach the debugger to the second process that it launches.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6wf8e4z.aspx

Comment: You can attach to multiple processes, so you can actually debug them both if you like.

Comment: Yeah I know how to attach to processes this way, just doesn't help when the code I need to test runs immediately. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: Have you seen this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361077/c-clr-remote-debugger-how-to-wait-until-attached If it's an option you could add code that waits for the debugger to be attached.

Comment: Thanks Greg, that seems like the best option for this.  Waiting for the debugger to be attached works best, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would think you would have to attach the debugger to the new process. If you want to do it manually you can use `Tools => Attach to Process`.

I think it is possible to attach a debugger programmatically, see below for some SO questions that address this:

- [Is it possible to communicate with the Visual Studio debugger programmatically while debugging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201504/is-it-possible-to-communicate-with-the-visual-studio-debugger-programmatically-wh)
- [How do I attach a process to the debugger in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986470/start-process-and-attach-debugger)

Comment: Thanks but not sure this is what I'm looking for.  There must be a way to start up another project in the solution by creating a new object or something, right?

Comment: What if you started the debugger in the other process on load? That way it will run almost right away (in the main constructor or whatever) - System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch() --- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If this is just a one-off kind of thing, the easiest option is probably to add a call to `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()` in the child process' source code at an early point of its initialization. Verify what you want to verify, then remove the `Break()` call.

If you're just looking to verify a set of command line arguments, then I'd probably just log them using whatever facility you might be using for logging - you might even wish to keep that logging around. Nice and simple.