# Can I set a conditional breakpoint in base class method which triggers only if it's an instance of specific derived class?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-c++, conditional-breakpoint

Let's say I have some base class A and two derived classes B and C. Class A has some method called f().

Is there a way to set a conditional breakpoint in A::f() in visual studio which will be hit only when my 'this' is actually an instance of class C?

For example

```
    void A::f()
    {
    some code and a breakpoint 
    }

    void foo(A* a)
    {
       a->f();
    }

    void bar()
    {
       A a;
       B b;
       C c;
       foo(&a); // breakpoint isn't hit
       foo(&b); // breakpoint isn't hit
       foo(&c); // breakpoint is hit
    }
```

I've managed to achieve it by testing virtual table pointer in breakpoint's condition but there's got to be a better(more easy) way.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Modifying source code as was suggested in comments is not kind of a solution I'm looking for. It has to be done only by means of VC++ debugger.

Comment: override the method in the derived class to simply call the base class and put your breakpoint there?

Comment: @AJG85 - yes, but it's possible that the binary cannot be modified.  fwiw I don't think conditional BPs allow this to be done.

Comment: Ah in that case the answer is "No"

Comment: To clarify the only possible way without changing source code would be to specify a break point condition which used `dynamic_cast<TypeYouWant>(this) != nullptr` or some other trickery which can't be evaluated as a symbol.

Answer (score 6):

You can. First of all, determine address of virtual table of type you wish to check against. Then setup a breakpoint with condition like 
    (arg).__vfptr != 0x01188298
where 0x01188298 is your type vtable's address. That's it.

Answer (score 3):

This is what `dynamic_cast` is for.

```
void A::f() {
    ...
    if (dynamic_cast<C*>(this)) {
        __debugbreak();
    }
    ...
}
```

If you have to do it by the debugger, then you will have to break, check the type using `dynamic_cast` in the Immediate window, and then continue if not.

Answer (score 1):

At the call site (i.e. where `foo` call is being made), it is nearly impossible to do that.
In the function itself, you may do this by having a virtual function, one of them would return `true`. All others would return `false`. If function returns `true`, you can call `DebugBreak` function itself. Or put its return value into some `bool` variable, and set conditional breakpoint. Yes, of course, this requires a virtual function to be added in all classes (or some). Additionally you can have one simple `bool` variable in base class, which will be assigned by derived class. The appropriate derived class (`C` in your case) can assign it as `true`. You can do this virtual/variable stuff in debug mode only using `_DEBUG` macro.

Another solution is to have a macro, which would call `foo` function. The implementation requires a virtual-function/member-variable in base class as described above, but `foo` won't be modified.

```
#define CALL_FOO(obj) \
  if(obj->member_variable_test) DebugBreak(); \
  foo(&obj);
```

And call `CALL_FOO` in place of `foo`:

```
CALL_FOO(&c); // breakpoint is hit
```

Though, this maybe unacceptable, but works. And breakpoint is hit exactly where you need!
You can make this macro work only in debug-build.

Answer (score 1):

[This post seems to hint at the possibility of programmatic debugging in Visual Studio.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201504/is-it-possible-to-communicate-with-the-visual-studio-debugger-programmatically-wh/201551#201551)

Alternatively, if you are able to compile the source in gcc or somehow utilize gdb, you may take advantage of the python scripting functionality to create complex conditional breakpoints.

[Here are some gdb python tutorials.](http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/PythonGdbTutorial)
[Here is the relevant gdb documentation.](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Python-API.html#Python-API)

Comment: Yes, I know it's possible with gdb. Unfortunetely I'm stack with Visual Studio.