# Break at throw for exception that is caught

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception, debugging

In the VS debugger, un-caught exceptions result in the program breaking at the point the exception is throw (or near enough) and in a state that lets you look at all the stack frames and there local variables up to that point.

Is there a way to get this same result (break at throw) but for an exception is caught at a particular point? I'm not interested in doing this for ALL exceptions or even all exception of a given type (that could get useless real quick) but if I could do it for a single try or catch block I'd be happy

somewhat related:

- [How to work around ‘Break when thrown’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201182/) (Is per class and I'm looking for per try/catch block)

Comment: Clarify plz: do you want to have the debugger stop on unhandled exceptions but only in certain methods? Or do you want to put a stop inside of your catch block?

Comment: @jcollum, nether. I want the debugger to stop at the point of throw but only if the exception is going to be caught at a given location.

Comment: The location that caused the exception ought to be in your stack trace (not 100% on that but). That's the best you're gonna get.

Answer (score 5):

Does the Debug -> Exceptions dialog do what you want? You  can select which Exceptions that will cause VS to break, regardless of whether they are caught or not. I don't know of a way to do this for only a certain part of the code, only based on the type of the exception thrown.

Comment: No that is per exception class (If I'm reading it right) I want anything caught at a given location.

Comment: Sadly, I don't know of any way to break when anything is thrown at a certain location. I could definitely see that coming in handy, though.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should be able to put a breakpoint on the last brace of your catch block. Or the throw command if you're re-throwing.

If you just need to have a breakpoint on any exception inside of a certain method do a re-throw.

```
try {  }
catch (Exception exc)
{ 
   throw;  // <-- breakpoint here
}
```

Edit: I was once in the habit of putting breakpoints on just about all of my exceptions. Found out the hard way that this slowed down the debugger in a big way once I got to about 25 breakpoints. May only be relevant to VS2005.

Edit2: The location that caused the exception ought to be in the exc object's StackTrace.

Comment: I don't think that works as that will break after the stack has been unwound to that point. :(

Comment: BCS: putting a break on the "throw"? There's no other way to do what he wants AFAIK.

Comment: If you know where the exception is going to be thrown, just put a try/catch block around that part of the code, and the ndo what jcollum says in his answer. Would that work?